# Statistical Test for Auto-correlation and Cross-correlation of pseudorandom numbers

Tags: statistics, correlation, hypothesis-testing

There are several tests like [NIST test suite](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documentation_software.html) or [testU01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestU01) which are proposed to investigate whether the sequences generated by a pseudorandom number generator can be considered random. In some applications like CDMA telecommunication systems, ideally PRNGs should have a delta-like auto-correlation and zero cross-correlation.

> My question is: Is there any statistical tests developed to investigate the independence of the sequences generated by such PRNGs to ensure they have delta-like auto-correlation and zero cross-correlation (with a desired significance level)